# How to solve modular equivalence with polynomial

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

I'm finding the solutions for the modular equation $x^2 -3x+2 \equiv 0\pmod{14}$. This is what I've done so far:

\begin{align}
0 & \equiv x^2 -3x+2 \pmod{14}\\
& \equiv (x-1)(x-2) \pmod{14} \\
\end{align}
This implies that two of the solutions are the polynomial's usual roots: **1, 2**.

This is where I get lost. I realize I should be using the following fact to find the other solutions, but don't know how to approach it.$$(x-1)(x-2) \overset{14}{\equiv} 0 \Leftrightarrow 14|(x-1)(x-2)$$ The provided answer says that **8,9** are the other solutions. How would I go about finding these?

Comment: Solve $2|x-1$ and $7|x-2$ and vice versa

Comment: Where do those come from? Because of $2 \times 7 = 14$? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: In general you can approach this type of congruence equations with composite modulus by solving first $0\equiv x^2-3x+2\pmod{2}$ and $0\equiv x^2-3x+2\pmod{7}$. You would get solutions of the form $x$ satisfying $x\equiv a\pmod{2}$ and $x\equiv b\pmod{7}$. With a prime modulus an equation like $0\equiv(x-1)(x-2)\pmod{p}$ implies that there are only the $2$ solutions that you expect. Then you can use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation) to combine these two conditions to the form $x\equiv c\pmod{14}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $14|(x-1)(x-2)$, we cannot conclude $14|x-1$ or $14|x-2$, because $14$ is not prime.

But $14=2\times7$, so $14|(x-1)(x-2)$ means $2|(x-1)(x-2)$ and $7|(x-1)(x-2)$.

Since $2$ and $7$ are prime, this means ($2|x-1 $ or $2|x-2$) and ($7|x-1$ or $7|x-2$).

Thus, there are four solutions (mod $14$).  Can you take it from here?

Comment: use [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) and the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(constructive_proof))